Azure function code changed in the portal is still sometimes doing what the old code did
I have made an queue trigger function that sends email adress to users using sendgrid, It has been running for almost a year and when I made any changes to it, it would run as expected.
I am always using the azure portal editor because I found it the easiest to use. The function runs on node.js and I dont use any deployment platforms to push code to it.
The problem started happening a few days ago when I made some changes to the code, and the portal would say that the code was successfully saved, even when I used the inbuild Run/Test it would run the new code but if I made queue using my website, even thought the queue had the new information it would still run the old code.
I've tried:

stopping and starting
restarting
making another function with the same code

but still nothing changed.

Try to deploy the same code to new app and check once.And also try to make changes after 1st deployment.

Yea, tried it, it worked once but just once and again still running the old code I dont really get it why.

Unable to repro the issue from my end,need more details about the code configuration and the Function App.

Do you have WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE setting in AppSettings?

No I dont I only use the portal to develop the code, but I have also asked this question on microsoft and they told me to try to develop it from vscode. I tried it but just messed up bad and I had to make the functions again. I will try to do it again maybe that will help.

In portal configuration section appsettings only check this setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE

I dont have such appsetting unfortunately it only appears there if I pair it with vscode if I understand it correctly.

Alright the fault was on my side I forgot and did not notice there was another function app in my azure portal that had the old code and when I looked at its invocations it was mostly the first one to run and then the new one did not because of it.
Moral of this story, please check all of your function apps to make sure that there is not some old dusted version of it that will make you problems like to me.
